# Duration#toMinutes in Runnable Every Second

Tags: java, runnable, duration, elapsedtime

I have a Duration field tracking elapsed time (in minutes) in a Runnable that currently loops every minute. I want to make it run the loop every second instead, but my checks are firing off multiple times. Below is the gist of my code.

```
Runnable runnable = (new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        Duration timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, now);
        long elapsedMinutes = timeElapsed.toMinutes();
        if (elapsedMinutes == (int) (totalRuntime() * .75)) {
            // Do something when partially done.
            // When set to second loops, this would run 60-ish times.
        }
    }
});
```

I tried adding a check, basically as follows, seeing if the seconds divided by 60 was a whole number, though that also didn't work.

```
long elapsedSeconds = timeElapsed.getSeconds();
if (elapsedSeconds / 60 == Math.round(elapsedSeconds / 60)) {
    // Then do other stuff
}
```

Can someone suggest something I can do to ensure everything in the loop only gets run once per minute instead of once per second.

You may also be asking why I'm making it a second instead of minute, it's because there's an if-statement wrapping the entire `run` method and it has to start something immediately if it doesn't pass.

Answer (score 0):

What about a Timer?

```
class CheckYourStuff extends TimerTask {
    public void run(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

from another point in your software

```
Timer t = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new CheckYourStuff(),0,1000);
```

Otherwise I would build an Executor and give him the schedule: [example code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Again, this isn't the problem. The loop runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Indeed, it does. If you want to keep the code you have written: where does `totalRuntime()` come from? What do you mean by "fire off multiple times"?  Another thing: did you invert "second" and "minute" in the second to last sentence?

Comment: totalRuntime() gets the total duration for it to run before resetting. It currently returns 60.

Comment: Instead of equals:`if(elapsedSeconds > =1)`;

Answer (score 0):

```
private double last = 0;

public void SomeMethod() {
    double now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    if(now - last >= 60) {
        //do stuff
        last = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    }
}
```

Do stuff will run once every 60 seconds. For better precision you can use System.nanoTime() but thats more expensive than currentTimeMillis().

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the Timer class:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("A second has passed");
    }
}, 1000, 1000);

Timer timerMin = new Timer();
timerMin.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("A minute has passed");
    }
}, 60_000, 60_000);
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. My loop runs perfectly fine.

Comment: @Spedwards I have edited it. You can schedule two Timers one that executes every second and one that executes every minute.